# The table width is not changing for HTML Outlook Emails

Tags: html, html-table, outlook, html-email

I am creating an HTML with 8 columns in the table. I want to change the size of every other column and make them smaller. It works fine with when I test the code but when I send it in a email in outlook the columns are not smaller.

I tried creating a th. style and applying it to the column but it did not work.

This is the code below.

```
type <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table {
        width:100%;
      }

      td {
        text-align: center;
        color: #332E33;
        font: arial;
      }

      a img {
        border: none;
        border-width: 0;
        border-style: none;
      }

      hr.line {
        height: 2px;
        width: 10px;
        top: 50px;
      }

     th.line_c {
        border-spacing: 0px;
        width:10px;  
      }
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <font size="2" Face="arial">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        </th>
        <th class="line_c">
          <hr class="line" width="100%"
        size="20" color="#9E2896">
        </th>
        <th>
          <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        </th>
        <th class="line_c">
          <hr class="line" width="100%"
        size="20" color="#9E2896">
        </th>
        <th>
          <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        </th>
        <th class="line_c">
          <hr class="line" width="100%"
        size="20" color="#9E2896">
        </th>
        <th>
          <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        </th>
      </tr>
   </table>here
```

Comment: Use `table-layout: fixed` on the table [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout). But, the hr will overflow the cell due to its size attribute.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Email is pretty backward sometimes. Try inlining the styles - i.e. not having them in a `<style>` block but in the items e.g. `<th style="...">`

Also if your image is natively pretty big, you'll need to specify the width you want them for Outlook Windows desktop, e.g. `<img width="100" ...>`. For other email clients, use `style="width:100%;"` or similar (concurrently).